# Python seleniumbase difference between windows and raspberry pi for a script

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, raspberry-pi3, seleniumbase

I made a python script based on seleniumbase to be able to connect to my tiktok account via google to post videos.

Everything works on my Windows environment, but on my raspberry pi, the script runs fine but seleniumbase can't connect me to the tiktok account with the google option.

Seleniumbase clicks on the google connection, fills in my information but once I'm back on tiktok I go back to the connection screen, whereas on windows the exact same script works without a problem.

I'm using the Driver(uc=True) function for information.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

The tests I've already done:
I can't use selenium because tiktok recognizes it and blocks the connection.
trying undetected_chromedriver doesn't work on raspberry pi.